# How to get a NSDateFormatter like contact.app used

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

[image]

How to get the `NSDateFormatter` like the one used to generate string on the right.

simply use the `setDoesRelativeDateFormatting` is not enough.

And using `NSCal` to figure out the date's relativity to now is quiet slow.

Especially when used in `UITableViewCell`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
f.dateFormat = @"yyyy MM dd";
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *your_Date;
NSString *a = [f stringFromDate today];
NSString *b = [f stringFromDate your_Date];
if (a isEqualToString:b){
 NSdateFormatter *forToday =... //with hours 
} else {
 NSDateFormatter *forDays = ...//days
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "fuzzy date" library such as [NSDate-TimeAgo](https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo).

Answer (score 0):

They are likely using 2 formatters...

maybe something like :

```
- (id)stringForDate:(NSDate*)date {
   if(date isToday]) return time
   else return date day
}
```